# Change the relative size of a subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two plots

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(121)
plt.subplot(122)
```

I want `plt.subplot(122)` to be half as wide as `plt.subplot(121)`. Is there a straightforward way to set the height and width parameters for a subplot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib different size subplots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388462/matplotlib-different-size-subplots)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By simply specifying the geometry with “`122`”, you're implicitly getting the automatic, equal-sized columns-and-rows layout.

To customise the layout grid, you need to get a little more specific. See “[Customizing Location of Subplot Using GridSpec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html)” in the Matplotlib docs.

Answer (score 54):

See the grid-spec tutorial:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/gridspec.html

Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

f = plt.figure()

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2,width_ratios=[2,1])
              
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also adjust the height ratio using a similar option in GridSpec

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't have access to import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec. Is there another way?

Comment: Is the issue that you're using an older version of matplotlib that doesn't support GridSpec? It's unclear in your question.

Comment: @thenickname : you can do `import matplotlib` and call `matplotlib.gridspac.GridSpec(1, 2, etc.)`

Comment: Is there a way to specify the size of a subplot/grid column in absolute terms? ie: To draw a custom colorbar with a fixed width?

Answer (score 23):

Yes, and if you want to reduce your code to a single line, you can put all kwargs that are to be passed to `matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec()`, into the `gridspec_kw` parameter of `plt.subplots()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[2,1], 'height_ratios':[2,1]})

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.plot.bar(ax=axs[0][0])
df.boxplot(ax=axs[0][1])
df.plot.line(ax=axs[1][0])
df.plot.kde(ax=axs[1][1])
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I like this way more than using `GridSpec` because it allows me quickly modify the existing code. Thanks!