# Matplotlib different size subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, figure, matplotlib-gridspec

I need to add two subplots to a figure. One subplot needs to be about three times as wide as the second (same height). I accomplished this using `GridSpec` and the `colspan` argument but I would like to do this using `figure` so I can save to PDF. I can adjust the first figure using the `figsize` argument in the constructor, but how do I change the size of the second plot?

Answer (score 641, accepted):

- As of `matplotlib 3.6.0`, `width_ratios` and `height_ratios` can now be passed directly as keyword arguments to [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots) and [`subplot_mosaic`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplot_mosaic), as per [What's new in Matplotlib 3.6.0 (Sep 15, 2022)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.6.0.html#subplots-subplot-mosaic-accept-height-ratios-and-width-ratios-arguments).

`f, (a0, a1) = plt.subplots(1, 2, width_ratios=[3, 1])`

`f, (a0, a1, a2) = plt.subplots(3, 1, height_ratios=[1, 1, 3])`

---

- Another way is to use the `subplots` function and pass the width ratio with `gridspec_kw`

  - [matplotlib Tutorial: Customizing Figure Layouts Using GridSpec and Other Functions](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html)
  - [`matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec) has available `gridspect_kw` options

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# generate some data
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
y = np.sin(x)

# plot it
f, (a0, a1) = plt.subplots(1, 2, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [3, 1]})
a0.plot(x, y)
a1.plot(y, x)

f.tight_layout()
f.savefig('grid_figure.pdf')
```

[image]

- Because the question is canonical, here is an example with vertical subplots.

```py
# plot it
f, (a0, a1, a2) = plt.subplots(3, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 1, 3]})

a0.plot(x, y)
a1.plot(x, y)
a2.plot(x, y)

f.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 270):

You can use [`gridspec`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) and `figure`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import gridspec

# generate some data
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
y = np.sin(x)

# plot it
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6)) 
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, width_ratios=[3, 1]) 
ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax0.plot(x, y)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax1.plot(y, x)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('grid_figure.pdf')
```

[image]

Answer (score 50):

In a simple way, different size sub plotting can also be done without `gridspec`:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
ax1 = plt.subplot(2,3,1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2,3,2)
ax3 = plt.subplot(2,3,3)
ax4 = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
axes = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 40):

I used `pyplot`'s `axes` object to manually adjust the sizes without using `GridSpec`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
y = np.sin(x)

# definitions for the axes
left, width = 0.07, 0.65
bottom, height = 0.1, .8
bottom_h = left_h = left+width+0.02

rect_cones = [left, bottom, width, height]
rect_box = [left_h, bottom, 0.17, height]

fig = plt.figure()

cones = plt.axes(rect_cones)
box = plt.axes(rect_box)

cones.plot(x, y)

box.plot(y, x)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 38):

Probably the simplest way is using `subplot2grid`, described in [Customizing Location of Subplot Using GridSpec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html).

```
ax = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 0))
```

is equal to

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
ax = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])
```

so bmu's example becomes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some data
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
y = np.sin(x)

# plot it
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
ax0 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 3), (0, 0), colspan=2)
ax0.plot(x, y)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 3), (0, 2))
ax1.plot(y, x)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('grid_figure.pdf')
```

[image]

Answer (score 27):

A nice way of doing this was added in `matplotlib 3.3.0`, [`subplot_mosaic`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic.html).

You can make a nice layout using an "ASCII art" style.

For example

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplot_mosaic("ABC;DDD")
```

will give you three axes on the top row and one spanning the full width on the bottom row like below

[image]

A nice thing about this method is that the `axes` returned from the function is a dictionary with the names you define, making it easier to keep track of what is what e.g.

```py
axes["A"].plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
```

You can also pass a list of lists to `subplot_mosaic` if you want to use longer names

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    [["top left", "top centre", "top right"],
     ["bottom row", "bottom row", "bottom row"]]
)

axes["top left"].plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
```

will produce the same figure

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can add the ratios directly in the gridspec instance

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2,2,width_ratios=[1,2])
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:,0])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,1])
```

[image: enter caption here]

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10411424/7758804), and has been flagged to a moderator for deletion. The other answer already covers`fig.add_subplot(gs[…])`