# seaborn: lmplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'figsize'

Tags: python, seaborn

How do I change the figure size for my lmplot in seaborn?

This is my current code, but apparently `figsize` isn't accepted.

```
sns.lmplot(x="x", y="y", hue="category", data=df,fit_reg=False,
       markers=["o", "x"], palette="Set1",figsize=(7,7));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since an `lmplot` is "figure-level", `figsize` is determined by two parameters, `size` and `aspect`. I think `size=7` will do what you want but I may be way off.

Here it is in the docs (search for "Change the height and aspect ratio of the facets"): http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html

Note: I have been endlessly confused by the exact same thing, and it would be really nice for sizing to have a consistent interface.

Comment: consistency for titfles and legends would also be great!

Comment: also how to make it to work with suplots?

Comment: @Intelligent-Infrastructure not sure, might be worth asking a new question! Or maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14770827/1594060

Answer (score 19):

Compare these two ways of setting the size of a chart:

#### Generating a linear model plot

```
sns.lmplot(data=conversion, x='Week Index', y='Lead-Ann', height=4, aspect=5)
```

#### Creating figure with a regression plot

```
plt.figure(figsize=(24,4))
sns.regplot(data=conversion, x='Week Index', y='Lead-Ann')
```

The difference is explained the Seaborn documentation: seaborn.lmplot

> Understanding the difference between regplot() and lmplot() can be a
> bit tricky. In fact, they are closely related, as lmplot() uses
> regplot() internally and takes most of its parameters. However,
> regplot() is an axes-level function, so it draws directly onto an axes
> (either the currently active axes or the one provided by the ax
> parameter), while lmplot() is a figure-level function and creates its
> own figure, which is managed through a FacetGrid. This has a few
> consequences, namely that regplot() can happily coexist in a figure
> with other kinds of plots and will follow the global matplotlib color
> cycle. In contrast, lmplot() needs to occupy an entire figure, and the
> size and color cycle are controlled through function parameters,
> ignoring the global defaults.

Comment: The `size` parameter has been renamed to `height`!

Answer (score 7):

In Seaborn 0.9.0, I think the correct way to do this is to use `height` (default of 5) to set the height of the figure and then use `aspect` (default of 1) to set the width.  `height * aspect = width`.

To make a larger square, just increase the height:

```python
sns.lmplot(x='x', y='y', hue='category', data=df, height=7);
```

To make it wider as well, increase the aspect ratio:

```python
sns.lmplot(x='x', y='y', hue='category', data=df, height=7, aspect=1.6);
```