# Is there a way to change the size of sublopts in MatplotLib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have the next dendrograms code

```
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.title('Enlace Promedio')
plt.xlabel('ID del Usuario de Netflix', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Distancia', fontsize=10)
dendrogram(z_average,leaf_font_size=10)

plt.subplot(1,3,2)

plt.title('Enlace Simple')
plt.xlabel('ID del Usuario de Netflix', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Distancia', fontsize=10)
dendrogram(z_simple,leaf_font_size=10)


plt.subplot(1,3,3)

plt.title('Enlace de Ward')
plt.xlabel('ID del Usuario de Netflix', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Distancia', fontsize=10)
dendrogram(z_ward,leaf_font_size=10)
plt.show()
```

And this output

[image]

How can I change the size of each of the subplots?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the figure size with subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770735/how-do-i-change-the-figure-size-with-subplots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use,

`f, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(a,b))`

And where the a,b are, pick the size

Reference:

[How do I change the figure size with subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770735/how-do-i-change-the-figure-size-with-subplots)