# size adjustment for matplolib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have 7 images that I need to show in a single matplotlib figure. But there are remaining a lot of whitespace after adding the images.
I tried following the second answer of this question: [How do I change the figure size with subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770735/how-do-i-change-the-figure-size-with-subplots)
but it did not work
Here are my code and the output
'images' is the list of PIL images stored

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(40,20))
rows=4
columns = 2
for i in range(1,7,1):
      subim = fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, i)
      subim.imshow(images[i-1])
```

output:
I want the small images to extend and fit the width of the plot
[image]

Comment: You need more columns.  The whitespace comes from the images keeping their original aspect ratio.  What about 2 rows and 4 columns?  Or 1 row and 7 columns?  If you really want to deform the images, you can use `imshow(..., aspect='auto')`.  You can also change the figsize to make enough room in the height.

Comment: ok thanks, it worked