# How to use `GridSpec()` with `subplots()`

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

There are several ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388462/matplotlib-different-size-subplots)) SO posts dealing with how to use `GridSpec` with subplotting in general. 
What i am trying to achieve to no avail, is to allow the use of `GridSpec` with `subplots`, something like this, Where i can replace the actual Array and list indexes with some loop controlled index :

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 1, height_ratios=[2, 2, 1, 1])        
tPlot, axes = plt.subplots(4, sharex=True, sharey=False)
tPlot.suptitle(node, fontsize=20)
axes[0].plot(targetDay[0], gs[0])
axes[1].plot(targetDay[1], gs[1])
axes[2].scatter(targetDay[2], gs[2])
axes[3].plot(targetDay[3], gs[3])
```

Needless to say that this code does not work, it just an example.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Rather than calling `gridspec.GridSpec` before `subplots`, you can send the `kwargs` to `GridSpec` from within your `subplots` call, using the `gridspec_kw` argument. From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots):

> `gridspec_kw` : dict
>
> Dict with keywords passed to the GridSpec constructor used to create the grid the subplots are placed on.

So, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tPlot, axes = plt.subplots(
        nrows=4, ncols=1, sharex=True, sharey=False, 
        gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[2,2,1,1]}
        )

tPlot.suptitle('node', fontsize=20)

axes[0].plot(range(10),'ro-') 
axes[1].plot(range(10),'bo-') 
axes[2].plot(range(10),'go-') 
axes[3].plot(range(10),'mo-') 

plt.show()
```

[image]