# Matplotlib: how can I adjust the figure size to be tight around subplots with **fixed** aspect ratios?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, aspect-ratio, matplotlib-basemap

I often make series of subplots with `mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap` projections, which generates geographic projections on axes with fixed aspect ratios. When I use `fig.tight_layout()`, this adjusts only the **axes** to be tight inside the bounding **figure** window -- so if the axes aren't allowed to have changed aspect ratios, this will often leave huge amounts of whitespace -- note this **cannot be fixed** by using `bbox_inches='tight'` in `figsave()`, because e.g. 2x2 networks of fixed-AR subplots will have extra *interior* whitespace.

Here's an example, where each axis has aspect 1:
[image]

Is there a way I can adjust the **figure** to be tight around the inner **axes** objects? Note this method would necessarily eliminate extra interior whitespace -- fixed-aspect ratio axes are centered in their `GridSpec` zone (e.g. the lower-right quadrant) until the *total* figure height/width is such that the aspect ratio of their `GridSpec` zone matches the axes aspect ratio.

Ideally, this method should work for the "**outer bounding box**" of each axes including its labels, titles, etc, rather than the box itself. One way would be to retrieve the aspect ratios of each subplot and adjust `figsize` accordingly, but that leaves the problem of room for titles, ticklabels, etc.; we really want the outer-bounding box aspect ratios.

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]?

Comment: @AndreySobolev Yup, just did.

Comment: I guess you need to adjust figure aspect ratio manually to get rid of the whitespace. If there are any other options, I'd be happy to know them too

Comment: I think it's hard to get something like the "outer bounding box' aspect". Did you have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475508/how-to-combine-gridspec-with-plt-subplots-to-eliminate-space-between-rows-of-s)? You would have to set the spacings manually, but a space of `0.3` is usually not too bad, I would guess.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Neat; is there a way to retrieve the auto-generated `hspace` and `wspace` between each subplot, or does it have to be explicitly declared when the subplot structure is drawn?

Comment: Isn't the main point here that the automatic settings do not apply for fixed aspect subplots? What would you gain from retrieving them?

Comment: Oh nevermind; I was thinking there could be some retrievable `hspace` and `wspace` refering to the "limiting" space between subplots -- the minimum space that would be left when the figure is reshaped such that "extra" whitespace disappears. At least, I think this would be the case if `hspace` and `wspace` were manually specified for a network of fixed-AR subplots.