# axis limit and sharex in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to show two images like these.

```
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np    
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, )
axes[0].imshow(np.random.random((3, 3)))
axes[1].imshow(np.random.random((6, 3)))
```

[image]
Then, I tried `sharex=True`, which unexpectedly changed the ylim of the two plots. Why?? Is it possible to align the plots without changing the y axis limits?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
axes[0].imshow(np.random.random((3, 3)))
axes[1].imshow(np.random.random((6, 3)))
```

[image]

I use python 3.5.2 and matplotlib 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default imshow axes have an equal aspect ratio. To preserve this, the limits are changed.

You have two options:

#### a) Dispense with equal aspect

Set the aspect to `"auto"`. This allows the subplots to take the available space and share their axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
   
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1,sharex=True ) 
axes[0].imshow(np.random.random((3, 3)), aspect="auto")
axes[1].imshow(np.random.random((6, 3)), aspect="auto")

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### b) Adjust the figure size or spacings

You can adjust the figure size or the spacings such that the axes actually match. You'd then also need to set the `height_ratios` according to the image dimensions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1,sharex=True, figsize=(3,5), 
                            gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":[1,2]} ) 
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, bottom=0.1, left=0.295, right=0.705, hspace=0.2)
axes[0].imshow(np.random.random((3, 3)))
axes[1].imshow(np.random.random((6, 3)))

plt.show()
```

[image]

This method either involves some trial and error or a sophisticated calculation, as e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43051546/4124317).

Comment: I did `fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True ,figsize=(1, 5))`. This appends some white spaces in both images, but preserves the aspect ratio.