# How to remove all padding in matplotlib subplots when using images

Tags: matplotlib, padding, subplot, imshow

When creating subplots with matplotlib i cannot get tight layout where there would not be any spaces between subplot items.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=(10,10),gridspec_kw = {'wspace':0, 'hspace':0})

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.ravel()):
    im = ax.imshow(np.random.normal(size=200).reshape([10,20]))
    ax.axis('off')

plt.tight_layout()
```

Subplots would consist of images. Seems like there is way to do this when you are not using images. So i assume, there is some configuration about imshow().
I would like to keep aspect ratio of images, but make subplots compact as possible.
this is what i get now, but as you can see, there is a **lot** of row padding
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egkdy.jpg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475508/how-to-combine-gridspec-with-plt-subplots-to-eliminate-space-between-rows-of-s

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071947/how-to-remove-the-space-between-subplots-in-matplotlib-pyplot