# Deleting Unnecessary Vertical White Space within Plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I want to create a figure that consists of 7 plots, 5 boxplots and 2 histograms. The first four boxplots are in the first two rows, followed by a row for the two histograms, and in the last row the last boxplot (figure below). When I try to create this in `matplotlib`, however, it creates a ton of vertical white space that is unnecessary (red rectangles in the provided images). I want to delete them, i.e. there should be as little as possible top and bottom white space in the plots. I have tried a few things, but nothing seems to work, [`subplot_adjust`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) (this seems to be the closest to what I want), [`margin`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html?highlight=margin#matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins). The link to my python code so far is below, with additional two links on this topic. Thank you for your help!

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dist = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)



FONT_SIZE = "xx-large"

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 26))
fig.tight_layout()

gs = fig.add_gridspec(4, 2)


fig_ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
fig_ax1.boxplot(
    dist,
    notch=True,
    vert=False)

fig_ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
fig_ax2.boxplot(
    dist,
    notch=True,
    vert=False)


fig_ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
fig_ax3.boxplot(
    dist,
    notch=True,
    vert=False)


fig_ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])
fig_ax4.boxplot(
    dist,
    notch=True,
    vert=False)



fig_ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, 0])
fig_ax5.hist(
    dist,
    bins=60)
fig_ax5.set_xlim(0, 0.02)


fig_ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, 1])
fig_ax6.hist(
    dist,
    bins=60)



fig_ax7 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3, :])
fig_ax7.boxplot(
    dist,
    notch=True,
    vert=False)
```

[image]

[Python code for the Figure](https://pastebin.com/zV44UrsM)

Some links for that issue.

[Matplotlib Issue on Margins](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1912)

[Zooming in and out using Axes.margins and the subject of "stickiness"](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axes_margins.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-axes-margins-py)

Comment: you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The normal way to create the axes like `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=2, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 1, 3, 1]})`. [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html). Related: [How to use `GridSpec()` with `subplots()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268742/how-to-use-gridspec-with-subplots)

Comment: Note that StackOverflow doesn't like a pastebin-link to code, because that link can get stale very quickly, leaving the question without contents. Also, github discussions of 7 years ago between the developers aren't usually very helpful for the current version.

Comment: @Sheldore Thank you! I see it know. That was too much unnecessary code. I have addressed this in the inline code, which also addresses JohanC remark.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for answer. I will give it try! Regarding the GitHub issue from 7 years: I know it is old, but it seemed to be relevant just a few years ago (scroll down in the issue).

Comment: @JohanC Unfortunately, your solution does not seem to work. In my cases, this makes the plots ugly and x-axis description disappears.

Comment: Please define "ugly". Did you try the other parameters of [`GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec), e.g. `'hspace'=0.6` to get more spacing between the rows? Please try to experiment with parameters.