# Python subplots containing line-graph and heatmaps

Tags: python, image, subplot, colorbar

I want to draw two subplots in one figure, one being a simple line graph y = f(x), and the other a 2D heatmap, [like the one shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSAeu.png).

But I wish to add a colorbar to the second plot. The code that I use is :

```
from pylab import*

fig = figure()
sub1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
sub2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

x=linspace(0,10,200)
y=exp(x)
sub1.plot(x,y)

x=linspace(-10,10,200)
y=linspace(-10,10,200)
xx,yy=meshgrid(x,y)
z=sin(xx)+cos(yy)
sub2.imshow(z)
sub2.colorbar()

show()
```

But this gives an error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ques2.py", line 16, in <module>
    sub2.colorbar()
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'colorbar'
```

What can I do?

And the output of the program obtained without manually adjusting the subplot parameters [is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIPyG.png). The two plots have very inequal sizes. Is there a way to mention the required size of subplot images in the program itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding colorbars, it is common practice to assign a variable to the image returned by `imshow` such as `img = sub2.imshow(z)` used below. Then you can add a colorbar to your image by telling `plt.colorbar` the image and the axis for the colorbar (in your case, `plt.colorbar(img, ax=sub2`).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
sub1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
sub2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

x = np.linspace(0,10,200)
y = np.exp(x)
sub1.plot(x,y)

x = np.linspace(-10,10,200)
y = np.linspace(-10,10,200)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = np.sin(xx)+np.cos(yy)

img = sub2.imshow(z)
plt.colorbar(img, ax=sub2)
```

As for changing the size of your subplots, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388462/matplotlib-different-size-subplots).

Comment: Is there a way to make the colorbar thinner. Because I think it is consuming a lot of space.

Comment: colorbar has a nice group of parameters for customizing size: fraction, shrink, and aspect. See [colorbar.make_axes()](http://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes) for details. Basically tweak those parameters as necessary until you're satisfied. The other parameters listed in the table are for customizing position/orientation.