# Matplotlib: enforce equal size (height) of subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, resize, subplot

I have a figure containing three subplots. The first subplot is an image (`imshow`), while the other two are distributions (`plot`).

Here's the code:

```
# collects data
imgdata = ...      # img of shape  (800, 1600, 3)    
x = ...            # one 1600-dimensional vector
y = ...            # one  800-dimensional vector

# create the figure 
f = plt.figure()    

# create subplots   
subplot_dim = (1, 3)
p_img = plt.subplot2grid(subplot_dim, (0, 0), aspect="auto")
p_x = plt.subplot2grid(subplot_dim, (0, 1), aspect="auto")
p_y = plt.subplot2grid(subplot_dim, (0, 2), aspect="auto")

p_img.imshow(imgdata, interpolation="None")
p_x.plot(x)         
p_y.plot(y)         


# save figure       
f.set_size_inches(21.0, 12.0)
f.savefig("some/path/image.pdf", dpi=80)
```

My problem is, that the two subplots `p_x`, `p_y` *always* have a greater height than the image subplot `p_img`.

Thus, the result always looks like this:

```
                  ###############   ###############   
                  #             #   #  *****      #
                  #        *****#   # *     *     #
###############   #     ***     #   # *      *    #
#             #   #    *        #   # *        *  #
#    image    #   #   *         #   #*           *#
#             #   #***          #   #*           *#
###############   ###############   ###############
     p_img              p_x               p_y
```

**How can I enforce an equal size** (or at least *height*) of `p_img`, `p_x` and `p_y`?

**EDIT:** Here is a **simple example code** that generates random data and uses `plt.show()` instead of saving a figure. However, one can easily see the same behaviour there: the image is much smaller (height) than the other subplots:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import image as mpimg
import numpy as np

imgdata = np.random.rand(200, 400, 3)  
x = np.random.normal(loc=100.0, scale=20.0, size=400)
y = np.random.normal(loc=150.0, scale=15.0, size=200) 

# create the figure
f = plt.figure()

# create subplots
subplot_dim = (1, 3)
p_img = plt.subplot2grid(subplot_dim, (0, 0), aspect="auto")
p_x = plt.subplot2grid(subplot_dim, (0, 1), aspect="auto")
p_y = plt.subplot2grid(subplot_dim, (0, 2), aspect="auto")

p_img.imshow(imgdata, interpolation="None")
p_x.plot(x)
p_y.plot(y)


# save figure
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try `plt.axis()` function to set axis dimensions

Comment: That did not change anything :( btw: isn't `axis()` taking a list of `[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]`? The `p_img`, `p_x` and `p_y` have a (pairwise) different y-axis. `800` for `p_img` (height of the image) and normally something in the interval [1, 10] for `y_max` of `p_x` and `p_y`. Therefore they never share the y-axis (scaling).

Comment: `gridspec`? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388462/matplotlib-different-size-subplots) question to see if its of any help

Comment: I've tested my example code with `gridspec` (created axes with `gridspec` instead of `subplot2grid` and added `height_ratios` to gridspec). This seems to enforce a certain width/height. However, I do not understand the scaling and it looks like the values are somehow absolute? Doesn't matplotlib have some method to make the height of subplots fixed? This looks like a huge design flaw to me...do one really has to determine every subplots width/height and then rescale it manually to get equal size subplots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by specifying it directly in the subplots like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import image as mpimg
import numpy as np

imgdata = np.random.rand(200, 400, 3)
x = np.random.normal(loc=100.0, scale=20.0, size=400)
y = np.random.normal(loc=150.0, scale=15.0, size=200)

# create the figure
f = plt.figure()

# create subplots
subplot_dim = (1, 3)
p_img = plt.subplot2grid(subplot_dim, (0, 0), aspect="auto")
p_x = plt.subplot2grid(subplot_dim, (0, 1), aspect="auto", adjustable='box-forced', sharex=p_img, sharey=p_img)
p_y = plt.subplot2grid(subplot_dim, (0, 2), aspect="auto", adjustable='box-forced', sharex=p_img, sharey=p_img)

p_img.imshow(imgdata, interpolation="None")
p_x.plot(x)
p_y.plot(y)
```

, which results in this:

[image: Same height for all matplotlib subplots]

The problem is your data does not have the same limits. So you'll have to make adjustments with `set_xlim` and `set_ylim`. I would also recommend testing other combinations for `sharey`, since they might provide better results.

Comment: Matplotlib 3.4 gives this error: `ValueError: 'box-forced' is not a valid value for adjustable; supported values are 'box', 'datalim'`