# Resize subplots using seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I have just recently started to use matplotlib and seaborn to plot my graphs. This is the code that I wrote so far

```
count = 1
l=[13,0,47,29,10]
plt.figure(figsize=(30,40))

for ww in l:
    temp_dict = defaultdict(list)
    entropies = list()
    for k,v in df.ix[ww].iteritems():
        e = 0
        for i in v:
            temp_dict[k].append(float(i))
            if not float(i) == 0:
                e += -1.0*float(i)*log10(float(i))
        entropies.append(e)

    y = entropies
    x=(range(len(entropies)))
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)

    plt.subplot(len(lista_autori),2,count)
    tdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dict, orient='columns')
    a = tdf.dropna()
    sns.set(font_scale=2)
    #sns.factorplot(size=2, aspect=1)
    sns.heatmap(a,linewidths=.5,cmap="RdBu_r")
    plt.xlabel(ur'year')
    plt.ylabel(ur'$PACS$')
    count +=1

    plt.subplot(len(lista_autori),2,count)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    x1 = (range(28))
    y1 =  [slope*i + intercept for i in x1]
    plt.plot(x1,y1)
    count +=1


plt.tight_layout();
```

The result is the following:

[image]

I would like to resize each row, assigning 2/3 of the row to the left hand side picture, the remaining to the right one. I tried to look at the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388462/matplotlib-different-size-subplots) but I found some difficulties when I have to mix ax and seaborn's heatmap. Any help or other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388462/matplotlib-different-size-subplots) directly tells you how to achieve a grid with unequal column width using GridSpec. I do not see much of a difference here, but maybe the following is more understandable for you, because it uses seaborn heatmaps, more than one row and no "ax".

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import gridspec
import seaborn as sns

# generate some data
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.2)
y = np.sin(x)
X = np.random.rand(3,4)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6)) 
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(5, 2, width_ratios=[2, 1]) 

for i in range(5):
    plt.subplot(gs[i*2+0])
    sns.heatmap(X)
    plt.subplot(gs[i*2+1])
    plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```