# How to increase size of a subplot in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using seaborn to draw some boxplot. Here is my code

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows = 8, ncols=2, figsize = (70,50))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.8)

i = 0
j = 0

for item in items:
    ...
    # create dist as a list
    sns.boxplot(data = dist, ax = axs[i][j])

    j += 1

    if j == 2:
        i += 1
        j = 0
```

I'm changing the length and width in figsize() but it does not change the width of my subplots! what's wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize subplots using seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179048/resize-subplots-using-seaborn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also set the aspect ratio by changing the `figsize`, so it may be better to use something like `figsize = (20, 80)` in your example rather than the current `(70, 50)`.

Otherwise, you may need to separately set the aspect ratio. (for example by adding `axs[i][j].set_aspect(1)` inside your `for` loop)

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `plt.figure(figsize=(60,50))` is creating a new empty figure different from your already declared fig from the first step. Set the `figsize` in your call to `plt.subplots`. It defaults to (6,4) in your plot since you did not set it. You already created your figure and assigned to variable `fig`. If you wanted to act on that figure you should have done `fig.set_size_inches(12, 5)` instead to change the size.

You can then simply call
`fig.tight_layout()` to get the plot fitted nicely.

Also, there is a much easier way to iterate through axes by using `flatten` on your array of `axes` objects. I am also using data directly from seaborn itself.

```py
# I first grab some data from seaborn and make an extra column so that there
# are exactly 8 columns for our 8 axes
data = sns.load_dataset('car_crashes')
data = data.drop('abbrev', axis=1)
data['total2'] = data['total'] * 2

# Set figsize here
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4, figsize=(12,5))

# if you didn't set the figsize above you can do the following
# fig.set_size_inches(12, 5)

# flatten axes for easy iterating
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    sns.boxplot(x= data.iloc[:, i],  orient='v' , ax=ax)

fig.tight_layout()
```