# Pyplot Create Intensity Plot From 1D Array

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I currently have a 1D array, representing intensity values with the index of the value being its x-position.

```
intensity_values = [0.10, 0.32, ... , 0.12, 0.23]
```

I want to create a subplot at the bottom of my figure with an intensity plot, visually showing the data as such.

[image: Gradient-Bar]

I've seen examples which require an array with 3-dimension to be able to fufil the data plot. How would I achieve this result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reshape `intensity_values` into a 2D NumPy array, you could use imshow:

```
ax.imshow(np.atleast_2d(intensity_values))
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
intensity_values = np.sin(x)

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/35881382/190597
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(
    nrows=2, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[7, 1],}, sharex=True)
ax0.plot(x, intensity_values)
ax1.imshow(np.atleast_2d(intensity_values), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'),
              extent=(0, np.pi, 0, 1))
plt.show()
```

[image]