# How to get two subplots to have the same height?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, subplot

I need to add a grayscale image and its histogram to a figure. 
The two subplots should be the same size, but the histogram is displayed twice as high as the image. How can I make both subplots to have the same height?

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

L = 256
img = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywPGr.png')
edges = np.arange(L+1)
hist, _ = np.histogram(img, bins=edges)
centers = edges[:-1]

fig, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax1.axis('off')
ax2.fill_between(centers, hist)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show(fig)
```

[image: Image and histogram]

I've tried the solutions proposed in the accepted answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654421/getting-the-same-subplot-size-using-matplotlib-imshow-and-scatter), but none of them worked for me.

Using automatic aspect on the image changes its aspect ratio (which is not acceptable):

```
ax1.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray, aspect='auto')
```

[image: First workaround]

Adding these two lines does not yield the desired result either:

```
asp = np.diff(ax2.get_xlim())[0] / np.diff(ax2.get_ylim())[0]
ax2.set_aspect(asp)
```

[image: Second workaround]

Comment: Try adding a background color to the image. Thats what I usually do

Comment: Try to change: `fig, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12,6))`. The problem with your current plot is that the plot region height is too large and this is leaving empty place in your left image.

Comment: Sorry, my answer to the linked question is only valid for square images. I will update it shortly.

Comment: Ok, done, see last paragraph of my answer to the linked question. I guess we can again close as dupe. Just mind that you have to set the aspect **after** drawing the `fill_between` curve, else you get that small line as shown in your last image here.

Comment: Thank you @Yilun Zhang, `figsize=(16,6)` did the trick. If you post this workaround as an aswer I will be pleased to accept it.