# Different Row heights for subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, row

I am trying to plot a figure with 8 rows of data. And I use the following line of code.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(9, 1, sharex=True, squeeze=True, figsize=(12, 18))
```

For this code, I have successfully produce 8 rows of data, with the same x-axis (sharex=True) and the same row heights. 
However, I want the just the first row of data to be of a different row height only (still same x-axis) and all.

How do I go about doing this?

Thank you fin advance for your kind assistance in helping me.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.

Apologies for it being a duplicate, but I really cannot find the answer at the suggested thread. Using GridSpec changes the column size, but what I want is row 1 of a certain hieght, row 2 of a different height etc.

Can you please guide me to the right thread? I am sincerly asking for help and not trying to be lazy and not searching the stack overflow.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was obvious. I reopened and gave an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35881382/4124317) where different widths of subplots can be achieved via the `width_ratios` keyword of the gridspec, you may use the `height_ratios` to achieve different heights of the subpplots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(5, 1, sharex=True, squeeze=True, 
                       gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios':[1,2,5,2,3]})

plt.show()
```

[image]