# python how to set a plot on the left of the first plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

im trying to plot 2 different plot, one at the left of the other, i try to use sublot from matplot but it is putting the seccond plot down the other i supose i use it wrong the subplot, this is my code

```
# Create bars

from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
bar = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.barh(plottl['Nombres'] ,plottl['Probas'])
presunto= plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
presunto = plt.subplot(122)
img=mpimg.imread((predict+names[0]+ '/'+ onlyfiles[0]))
mgplot = plt.imshow(img)

plt.show()
predictions=[]
```

now here is a pic. of what is happening

[image]

i was hopping you can helpme to solve this, thank you all in advance

edit: i put here the asked picture

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating 2 figures instead of 2 subplots, although it's better to use `gridspec` when you want to draw subplots with different sizes. look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388462/matplotlib-different-size-subplots)

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
bar = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.barh(plottl['Nombres'] ,plottl['Probas'])

presunto = plt.subplot(122)
img=mpimg.imread((predict+names[0]+ '/'+ onlyfiles[0]))
mgplot = plt.imshow(img,aspect="auto")

plt.show()
```

Comment: that worked very nice, but there is just one thing, the second plot is to small is any way to make it bigger in length and height, just the second picture, thanks for helping me

Comment: send the picture of the resulting plot

Comment: i added the pic to the question, the thing is that i want it to look bigger to get a better apresiation of the face and body in the picture

Comment: you should add `aspect="auto"` when you are using `imshow`

Comment: it would automatically set aspect on the image

Answer (score 1):

You are creating 2 figures, instead of one with 2 subplots. remove the line `presunto= plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))` and it should work.