# How to make subplots having different range on each axis have the same figure size using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting an a line plot and an image side by side. Here is my code and the current output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#creating some random data
np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'px_last': 100 + np.random.randn(1000).cumsum()},
    index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=1000, freq='B'),
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax[0].plot(df.index, df['px_last'])
#reading the image
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kornelski/pngquant/master/test/img/test.png'
im = plt.imread(url)
implot = ax[1].imshow(im)
```

[image: Current output]

The image is scaled down and the lineplot is enlarged on the y-axis. I want both figures to have the same size vertically (y-axis) - I want to have the vertical height of the line plot reduced to have the same size of the image.

I tried changing the figure size of the subplots and editing the gridspec parameter as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388462/matplotlib-different-size-subplots) but that only changes the width of the image, not the height. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to use automatic aspect on the image.

```
implot = ax[1].imshow(im, aspect="auto")
```

This will make the shape of your image same as your other plot.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the overall graph size and adding the subplot will look like this.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

ax1.plot(df.index, df['px_last'])
#reading the image
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kornelski/pngquant/master/test/img/test.png'
im = plt.imread(url)
implot = ax2.imshow(im)

plt.show()
```

[image]