# How can I change the size of each graph in matplotlib using subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this code to graph a series, it is working but the size isn't enough:

```
    plt.subplot(1,3,1) 
    
    plt.bar(dias_creacion.index,dias_creacion)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(7),('Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado','Domingo'),rotation=45)
    plt.title('Días de creación')
    
    plt.subplot(1,3,2)
    
    plt.bar(dias_primera_conversion.index,dias_primera_conversion)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(7),('Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado','Domingo'),rotation=45)
    plt.title('Primeras conversiones')
    
    plt.subplot(1,3,3)
    
    plt.bar(dias_ultima_conversion.index,dias_ultima_conversion)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(7),('Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado','Domingo'),rotation=45)
    plt.title('Ultimas conversiones')
    
    plt.show()
```

I tried this:

```
plt.subplot(1,3,1) 
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.bar(dias_creacion.index,dias_creacion)
plt.xticks(np.arange(7),('Lunes','Martes','Miercoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sabado','Domingo'),rotation=45)
plt.title('Días de creación')
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: I think this might answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388462/matplotlib-different-size-subplots

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib different size subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388462/matplotlib-different-size-subplots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)` is my go to to change figure size. Make sure to place it at the top of your graph code (even before `plt.subplot(1,3,1)`)