# How do I get the longer plot on top using subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, subplot

This is a simple question, based on this previously asked subplots question: [Matplotlib different size subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388462/matplotlib-different-size-subplots)

But how do I get the larger plot on top? I know that in `plt.subplots()`, it's nrows and ncolumns, but I am having trouble placing the larger plot on top and the 3 smaller ones below:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2,3,1)
ax3 = plt.subplot(2,3,2)
ax4 = plt.subplot(2,3,3)

axes = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]
```

[image]

Hoping to get the the bottom plot above the top 3.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a 2 x 3 plot layout and make the first plot span all three columns.

See [`subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html):

> index can also be a two-tuple specifying the (first, last) indices
> (1-based, and including last) of the subplot, e.g., fig.add_subplot(3,
> 1, (1, 2)) makes a subplot that spans the upper 2/3 of the figure.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

ax1 = plt.subplot(2,3,(1,3))
ax2 = plt.subplot(2,3,4)
ax3 = plt.subplot(2,3,5)
ax4 = plt.subplot(2,3,6)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! is there a way to change the figsize of only the top figure? or change the figsize of individual figures within the subplot?

Comment: You probably mean the Axes size (figsize is the size of the complete Figure with the 4 Axes). You can change the horizontal and vertical spacing and margins but for complex layouts you may need nested gridspecs. Maybe it's better to ask a separate question with a sketch of how the result should look like.