# How to plot Matplotlib subplots that cover more than one row/column in the grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot 1 main square graph (3x3) surrounded by 7 small squared graphs (1x1). Like in figure:
[image]

If the 7 plots are not present main graph should cover all the window, without empty sides.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388462/matplotlib-different-size-subplots)

- it is answered how to give different subplots different sizes. The biggest you can make the main one is a quarter of the figsize with `plt.subplot(2,2,1)`.
- with heigh-ratios, I can make the main plot bigger, but on the right and bottom, I have only a rectangular cell:
  https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_hist.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-hist-py

[image]

Comment: Use `subplot_mosaic`. The mosaic will have four rows, something like `AAAB`,`AAAC`,`AAAD`,`EFGH`.