# Matching graph sizes in matplotlib with and without make_axes_locatable->divider colorbars

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, scale

I have 4 graphs in a 2x2 grid, but only want the two on the right to have bars (scale applies by row). I am using of the form

```
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
```

to get the colorbars to match the size of these two graphs. However this makes the two with colorbars a different size from the two without, which both looks bad and eliminates the ability to put axis only on the outer edges. I tried just not having the colorbar call (with the divider call), but of course this leaves an empty white box and numbers on the side. How do I get all of the graphs, with and without colorbars, to have a consistent size without putting bars on all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Use `GridSpec` to make a custom set of subplots, then add the color bar to the final column.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 3, width_ratios=[10,10,1])

ax = np.empty([2,3],dtype=np.object)
im = np.empty([2,2],dtype=np.object)

for m in range(2):
    for n in range(2):
        ax[m,n] = plt.subplot(gs[m,n])
        im[m,n] = ax[m,n].imshow(np.random.rand(10,10))

for i in range(2):
    ax[i,2] = plt.subplot(gs[i,2])
    plt.colorbar(im[i,1],cax=ax[i,2])

plt.show()
```

See also:
[Python/Matplotlib - Change the relative size of a subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083763/python-matplotlib-change-the-relative-size-of-a-subplot)