# Issues with python matplotlib and subplot sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create a figure with 6 sub-plots in python but I am having a problem. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

g_width = 200
g_height = 200
data = numpy.zeros(g_width*g_height).reshape(g_height,g_width)

ax1 = plt.subplot(231)
im1 = ax1.imshow(data)
ax2 = plt.subplot(232)
im2 = ax2.imshow(data)
ax3 = plt.subplot(233)
im3 = ax3.imshow(data)
ax0 = plt.subplot(234)
im0 = ax0.imshow(data)
ax4 = plt.subplot(235)
im4 = ax4.imshow(data)
ax5 = plt.subplot(236)
ax5.plot([1,2], [1,2])
plt.show()
```

The above figure has 5 "imshow-based" sub-plots and one simple-data-based sub-plot. Can someone explain to me why the box of the last sub-plot does not have the same size with the other sub-plots? If I replace the last sub-plot with an "imshow-based" sub-plot the problem disappears. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you mean that the actual plotting area is smaller? This might be due to the y-axis values.  In that case, you can use [subplots_adjust](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust)

Comment: Does this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083763/python-matplotlib-change-the-relative-size-of-a-subplot help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aspect ratio is set to `"equal" for the 5`imshow()`calls (check by calling`ax1.get_aspect()`) while for`ax5`it is set to`auto`which gives you the non-square shape you observe. I'm guessing`imshow()` defaults to equal while plot does not.

To fix this set all the axis aspect ratios manually e.g when creating the plot `ax5 = plt.subplot(236, aspect="equal")`

On a side node if your creating many axis like this you may find this useful:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=2, subplot_kw={'aspect':'equal'})
```

Then `ax` is a tuple (in this case `ax = ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (ax4, ax5, ax6))`) so to plot in the `i`, `j` plot just call

```
ax[i,j].plot(..)
```