# Subplots: tight_layout changes figure size

Tags: python, subplot

Changing the vertical distance between two subplot using tight_layout(h_pad=-1) changes the total figuresize. How can I define the figuresize using tight_layout?

Here is the code:

```
#define figure
pl.figure(figsize=(10, 6.25))

ax1=subplot(211)
img=pl.imshow(np.random.random((10,50)), interpolation='none')
ax1.set_xticklabels(()) #hides the tickslabels of the first plot

subplot(212)
x=linspace(0,50)
pl.plot(x,x,'k-')
xlim( ax1.get_xlim() ) #same x-axis for both plots
```

And here is the results:
[image]

If I write

```
pl.tight_layout(h_pad=-2)
```

in the last line, then I get this:

[image]

As you can see, the figure is bigger...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GridSpec object to control precisely width and height ratios, as answered [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083763/python-matplotlib-change-the-relative-size-of-a-subplot) and [documented here](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html).

Experimenting with your code, I could produce something like what you want, by using a `height_ratio` that assigns twice the space to the upper subplot, and increasing the `h_pad` parameter to the `tight_layout` call. This does not sound completely right, but maybe you can adjust this further ...

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

#define figure
fig = pl.figure(figsize=(10, 6.25))

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[2,1])

ax1=subplot(gs[0])
img=pl.imshow(np.random.random((10,50)), interpolation='none')
ax1.set_xticklabels(()) #hides the tickslabels of the first plot

ax2=subplot(gs[1])
x=np.linspace(0,50)
ax2.plot(x,x,'k-')
xlim( ax1.get_xlim() ) #same x-axis for both plots
fig.tight_layout(h_pad=-5)
show()
```

There were other issues, like correcting the imports, adding numpy, and plotting to `ax2` instead of directly with `pl`. The output I see is this:

[image: Corrected figure]

Comment: I thought this is the answer but unfortunatley fig.tight_layout still changes the figure size. You can test it by switching fig.tight_laout on and off:                                       fig = pl.figure(figsize=(10, 6.25))
pl.imshow(np.random.random((10,50)), interpolation='none')
#fig.tight_layout(h_pad=0)

Answer (score 0):

This case is peculiar because of the fact that the default aspect ratios of images and plots are not the same. So it is worth noting for people looking to remove the spaces in a grid of subplots consisting of images only or of plots only that you may find an appropriate solution among the answers to this question (and those linked to it): [How to remove the space between subplots in matplotlib.pyplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071947/how-to-remove-the-space-between-subplots-in-matplotlib-pyplot).

The aspect ratios of the subplots in this particular example are as follows:

```
# Default aspect ratio of images:
ax1.get_aspect()
# 1.0

# Which is as it is expected based on the default settings in rcParams file:
matplotlib.rcParams['image.aspect']
# 'equal'
```

```
# Default aspect ratio of plots:
ax2.get_aspect()
# 'auto'
```

The size of `ax1` and the space beneath it are adjusted automatically based on the number of pixels along the x-axis (i.e. width) so as to preserve the 'equal' aspect ratio while fitting both subplots within the figure. As you mentioned, using [`fig.tight_layout(h_pad=xxx)`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html) or the similar [`fig.set_constrained_layout_pads(hspace=xxx)`](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html) is not a good option as this makes the figure larger.

To remove the gap while preserving the original figure size, you can use `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=xxx)` or the equivalent `plt.subplots(gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=xxx))`, as shown in the following example:

```
import numpy as np                 # v 1.19.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # v 3.3.2
np.random.seed(1)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(10, 6.25),
                               gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=-0.206))

# For those not using plt.subplots, you can use this instead:
# fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-0.206)

size = 50
ax1.imshow(np.random.random((10, size)))
ax1.xaxis.set_visible(False)

# Create plot of a line that is aligned with the image above
x = np.arange(0, size)
ax2.plot(x, x, 'k-')
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())

plt.show()
```

[image: no_hspace]

I am not aware of any way to define the appropriate `hspace` automatically so that the gap can be removed for any image width. As stated in the docstring for [`fig.subplots_adjust()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=subplots_adjust#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust), it corresponds to the *height of the padding between subplots, as a fraction of the average axes height*. So I attempted to compute `hspace` by dividing the gap between the subplots by the average height of both subplots like this:

```
# Extract axes positions in figure coordinates
ax1_x0, ax1_y0, ax1_x1, ax1_y1 = np.ravel(ax1.get_position())
ax2_x0, ax2_y0, ax2_x1, ax2_y1 = np.ravel(ax2.get_position())

# Compute negative hspace to close the vertical gap between subplots
ax1_h = ax1_y1-ax1_y0
ax2_h = ax2_y1-ax2_y0
avg_h = (ax1_h+ax2_h)/2
gap = ax1_y0-ax2_y1
hspace=-(gap/avg_h) # this divided by 2 also does not work

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=hspace)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Maybe someone else has a solution for this.

It is also worth mentioning that I tried removing the gap between subplots by editing the y positions like in this example:

```
# Extract axes positions in figure coordinates
ax1_x0, ax1_y0, ax1_x1, ax1_y1 = np.ravel(ax1.get_position())
ax2_x0, ax2_y0, ax2_x1, ax2_y1 = np.ravel(ax2.get_position())

# Set new y positions: shift ax1 down over gap
gap = ax1_y0-ax2_y1
ax1.set_position([ax1_x0, ax1_y0-gap, ax1_x1, ax1_y1-gap])
ax2.set_position([ax2_x0, ax2_y0, ax2_x1, ax2_y1])
```

Unfortunately, this (and variations of this) produces seemingly unpredictable results, including a figure resizing similar to when using `fig.tight_layout()`. Maybe someone else has an explanation for what is happening here behind the scenes.