# Remove separation between subplots in horizontal direction

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have four 2D arrays I want to plot in four subplots using imshow. I want the separation between these subplots to be removed, making the subplots touch each other, similar to the [Matplotlib Documentation](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html?highlight=creating%20multiple%20subplots%20using%20plt%20subplots) (second to last example). My attempt is

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row', gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0, 'wspace': 0})
(ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4) = axs

ax1.imshow(im1)
ax2.imshow(im2)
ax3.imshow(im3)
ax4.imshow(im4)

for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ax.label_outer()

plt.show()
```

This produces

[image]

The separation in the vertical direction seems to be correctly removed, but I still have a separation in the horizontal direction. Does anyone know how I can get rid of that as well here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41075262/4932316) answer of [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest). I have prepared the following pseudo code based on it for your question. You can try it and see if it works for you.

```
from matplotlib import gridspec

nrow, ncol = 2, 2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6)) 

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrow, ncol,
         wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0, 
         top=1.-0.5/(nrow+1), bottom=0.5/(nrow+1), 
         left=0.5/(ncol+1), right=1-0.5/(ncol+1)) 

ims = [im1, im2, im3, im4]

c = 0 # Counter for the ims array

for i in range(nrow):
    for j in range(ncol):
        ax= plt.subplot(gs[i,j])
        ax.imshow(ims[c])
        ax.set_xticklabels([])
        ax.set_yticklabels([])
        c += 1

for ax in fig.get_axes():
    ax.label_outer()
```