# matplotlib combining subplots into a single plot with no axis and no gaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, visualization

I have an image which looks like so:

[image]

It was generated using matplotlib using:

```
for slice_idx in range(mandrill_t.highpasses[1].shape[2]):
    print(slice_idx)
    subplot(2, 3, slice_idx+1)
    imshow(np.abs(mandrill_t.highpasses[1][:,:,slice_idx]), cmap='Spectral', clim=(0, 1))
```

However, for my use case, I would like all these 6 images in a single image with no gaps or axis - I do not have an example output image to show, but essentially, I would like them stacked horizontally (3 of them) and vertically (2 of them) so that the 6 images are a single image.

I tried looking around for similar problems to draw inspiration from, but no luck so far :(

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] we can play around with

Comment: @Joooeey did you see what I have written? If iam able to provide a reproducible example the problem would be solved. Essentially I want to know how you can combine the subplots into a single plot.

Comment: you can provide a reproducable example that produces a plot similar to the one in your image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the space between subplots in matplotlib.pyplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071947/how-to-remove-the-space-between-subplots-in-matplotlib-pyplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the grid parameters:

- 2 rows
- 3 columns
- 0 width space
- 0 height space

with [**`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html):

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 3, gridspec_kw = {'wspace': 0, 'hspace': 0})
```

Then you can loop over created axes and, for each one of them, you have to show the image and set axis to `'tight'` firtsly and `'off'` secondly:

```
for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.imshow(img)
    ax.axis('tight')
    ax.axis('off')
```

Your code would be slighlty different, since you are plotting different images for each `ax`.

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = plt.imread('img.jpeg')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 3, gridspec_kw = {'wspace': 0, 'hspace': 0})

for ax in axes.flatten():
    ax.imshow(img)
    ax.axis('tight')
    ax.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: setting to "tight" will change the aspect ratio.

Comment: @Zephyr: this is awesome. Joey it does not seem to change the aspect ratio: but perhaps my image is square so I dont see it?

Comment: Did you measure it? Did it stay exactly square? From your screenshot it looks like the plot spots in the 2x3 grid are almost square but not exactly.

Comment: @Joooeey well all my 6 images are exactly 128x128 - so I presume there cannot be any change in a/r? or am i not understanding you? :(

Comment: @JohnM this can only work by happenstance.  For a general figure size or sized image there will be white space using this approach.  Try changing the size of your figure.

Comment: @JodyKlymak no, if you call `ax.axis('tight')`, the image will be stretched, no white space. Unless as you say, the individual plots end up square by chance. How to solve that problem is well explained in answers to the duplicate question that I linked.

Comment: @Joooeey. Yes, that will happen if you are OK with your image being arbitrarily stretched.  Most people are not.

Answer (score 1):

That's what [`GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec) is for (see [`plt.subplots` docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)):

Just add the following line at the start:

```
subplots(2, 3, gridspec_kw={"wspace": 0, "hspace": 0})
```

You might also have to set some plot elements to invisible but it's hard to figure out exactly which without an MCVE.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am close now: https://i.imgur.com/PKD6i72.png but I still see whitespace which I want to avoid :(

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41075262/4691830