# Keep figure size fixed when removing padding

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to remove the padding around a figure and save it with exactly specified dimensions:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
x = [1,2,3]
ax.plot(x, x)
fig.savefig("test.pdf", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.01)
```

Unfortunately, doing it this way reduces the dimensions of the resulting figure (in this case to `8.2 in, 4.1 in`). A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144993/subplots-tight-layout-changes-figure-size) has been asked here quite a while ago, but does not consider the complete removal of the padding.

Comment: You need to remove `bbox_inches='tight'` and `pad_inches=0.01`. This will change the figure size. The linked answer tells you to use `fig.tight_layout()` instead, and ***is*** in fact working correctly.

Comment: You are right about that, thanks for pointing it out. My main problem however is to completely remove the padding around the figure without a change of dimension which is why I invoke the `pad_inches=0.01` argument.

Comment: You may want to scale the content ***within*** the figure. `fig.tight_layout()` can be used for that, or else `fig.subplots_adjust(...)` with appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by ImportanceOfBeingErnest, instead of using the `bbox_inches` and `pad_inches` arguments in `fig.savefig` which changes the dimensions of the figure, one can use

```
fig.tight_layout(pad=0.01)
```

to scale the content within the figure instead, keeping the figure size fixed.